# App crashing after rxJava upgrade to 2.2.20

Tags: android, rx-java

I upgraded my Rxjava version from 2.1.10 to 2.2.20, after this my app is continuously crashing on launch with below exception.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No instance field qs of type Lio/reactivex/internal/fuseable/QueueDisposable; in class
> Lcom/tspoon/traceur/ObservableOnAssembly$OnAssemblyObserver; or its
> superclasses (declaration of
> 'com.tspoon.traceur.ObservableOnAssembly$OnAssemblyObserver' appears
> in /data/app/-Yk-Whoe9EoURHPyNyYsVfQ==/base.apk!classes4.dex)
> at com.tspoon.traceur.ObservableOnAssembly$OnAssemblyObserver.requestFusion(ObservableOnAssembly.java:67)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.onSubscribe(ObservableObserveOn.java:86)
> at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BasicFuseableObserver.onSubscribe(BasicFuseableObserver.java:66)
> at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BasicFuseableObserver.onSubscribe(BasicFuseableObserver.java:66)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableReplay$ReplaySource.subscribe(ObservableReplay.java:1009)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableReplay.subscribeActual(ObservableReplay.java:170)
> at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
> at com.tspoon.traceur.ObservableOnAssemblyConnectable.subscribeActual(ObservableOnAssemblyConnectable.java:42)
> at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableAutoConnect.subscribeActual(ObservableAutoConnect.java:46)
> at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
> at com.tspoon.traceur.ObservableOnAssembly.subscribeActual(ObservableOnAssembly.java:43)
> at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn.subscribeActual(ObservableObserveOn.java:45)
> at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
> at com.tspoon.traceur.ObservableOnAssembly.subscribeActual(ObservableOnAssembly.java:43)
> at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
> at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12253)
> at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12181)

In code i define the observer like below

```
 private Subject<ChangeEvent> callStateEventPs = PublishSubject.<ChangeEvent>create().toSerialized();
private Observable<ChangeEvent> eventCachingObservable = callStateEventPs.replay(1).autoConnect();

//and later i was trying to subscribe it like below
Disposable disposable = eventCachingObservable
                .observeOn(mainThread())
                .subscribe(StateEvent -> doMyJob(), ErrorHandler::logError);

//in gradle file
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.20'
```

any guidance will be really helpful, i am fully blocked in this.

Comment: Traceur appears to rely on a very old RxJava version. Try [this](https://github.com/T-Spoon/Traceur/pull/11) workaround.

Comment: Switch to coroutines

Comment: thanks @akarnokd, this is really saved me, worked like charm.